# How to replace fragment in ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

The ViewPager, ViewPagerAdapter, TabLayout and three fragments Fragment, Fragment2, Fragment 3 are shown in ViewPager as 2 fragment. How can Fragment 1-3 be represented dynamically?

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
ViewPagerAdapter mVPAdapter = newViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
mVPAdapter.addFrag(new Fragment_1(), "");
mVPAdapter.addFrag(new Fragment_2(), "");
viewPager.setAdapter(mVPAdapter); 
tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Comment: in view pager 2 fragments load at one time, when you swip left or right then next one will load. if you have implemented correctly in adapter

Comment: Thanks @KhizarHayat could you refer me to further readings on this?

Comment: this tutorial can help you more https://dzone.com/articles/android-tutorial-using